# How I can set the size of a layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc.) as a percentage?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I need to adjust content depending on the size of the screen, such as HTML which can be used porcetage. I show my code and what I need to do

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_happyhour_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#363636"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dip" >  
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="12dip" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">    
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/el_nombre" 
    android:layout_width="170dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nombre_happyhour"
                android:layout_width="170dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="#ffffff" 
                android:textSize="19sp"
                android:tag="bold"
               />    
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/precios_happy" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dip">              
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vertical1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/precio_happyhour"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vertical2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:src="@drawable/vertical" 
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hp"
        android:layout_width="24dip"
        android:layout_height="24dip"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/happy" 
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bot" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/descripcion"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/la_descripcion"
        android:layout_width="250dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" 
        android:textColor="#ffffff" 
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dip"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_tag"
        android:layout_width="5.84mm"
        android:layout_height="4.21mm"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/agotado"
        android:paddingLeft="30sp" 
        />      
    </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="290dip"
    android:layout_height="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/divierblanco"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
```

The LinearLayout containing 2 LinearLayout (the_name, precio_happy), one for a name and the other for the price along with some pictures of ornamental I encesito is that the size of "the_name" is like 60% to adjust the name and obimante the price is 40%, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the width or height that you want to be relative to 0dp, then use layout_weight to set a percentage.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:text="left" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".70" /> 

    <Button
        android:text="right" 
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".30" />

</LinearLayout>
```

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use android:weight for that. Set the container with weightsum=100, and then you can set the sizes relatively.

Answer (score 0):

We can use java api to implement layout of screen.Thus we will able to develop UI dynamically.

Also to adjust our UI percentage wise depending on device dimension,we can use  Display class of android which gives us screen width and height at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method it will rearrange your view for percent you passed.

```
setHeightInPercent(this, lvFavouriteCountries, 0.23f);

public static void setHeightInPercent(Context context, View view,
            float percentage) {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int height = display.getHeight();

        int heightForView = (int) (height * percentage);
        LayoutParams layoutParmas = view.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParmas.height = heightForView;

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParmas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of Linear Layouts and Weight is not considered as a best practice according to official guideline for multiple screens.